# SQLite: Using COALESCE inside a CASE statement

Tags: sqlite, case, coalesce

I have two tables: one with record of a person with initial number, and a second one with records of changes to this number.

During a join, I do `coalesce(latest_of_series, initial)` to get a singular number per person. So good so far.

I also group this numbers into a groups, on order these groups separately. I know I can do:

```sql
select
  coalesce(latest, initial) as final,
  case
    when coalesce(latest, inital) > 1 and coalesce(latest, inital) < 100 then 'group 1'
    -- other cases
  end as group
-- rest of the query
```

but that's of course horribly unreadable.

I tried:

```sql
select
  coalesce(latest_of_series, initial_if_no_series) as value,
  case
    when value > 1  and value < 100   then 'group 1'
    -- rest of the cases
  end as group
-- rest of the query
```

but then the sqlite complains that `there's no column "value"`

Is there really no way of using previous result of coalesce as a "variable"?

Comment: Use a subquery.

Comment: @forpas it’s already a clusterfuck of sub queries and joins :-)

Comment: But I see that you accepted the answer that proposes a subquery.

Comment: But let's be honest, there really is no other way to do this.

Comment: @forpas I accept that it's a limitation of SQL and there's no other way

Comment: Maybe "limitation" is  the wrong word. It's a logical requirement. It follows unconditionally from the way SQL works. You could argue that it would be nice if it were different, but ultimately, if you think it through, it's the only way it *can* work. Some SQL dialects might sugar-coat it, e.g. MySQL lets you do things like `SELECT a * 2 as b, count(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY b;` but *actually* it just replaces those definitions for you as it builds the query plan. The real order of events is retained. So you might see as an SQL limitation what's an absense of syntactic sugar.

Comment: @tomalak absence of this particular syntactic sugar then

Comment: Every syntactic sugar is a leaky abstraction. You still have to understand how things *really* work in order to appreciate the syntactic sugar and use it efficiently. And once you know that, "just writing the thing down" is less of a work-around than it might feel like at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an SQLite limitation. That's an SQL limitation.

All the column names are decided *as one*. You can't define a column in line 2 of your query and then refer to it in line 3 of your query. All columns derive from the tables you select, each on their own, they can't "see" each other.

But you can use nested queries.

```
select
  value,
  case 
    when value >= 1    and value < 100 then 'group 1'
    when value >= 100  and value < 200 then 'group 2'
                                       else 'group 3'
  end value_group
from
  (
    select
      coalesce(latest_of_series, initial_if_no_series) as value
    from
      my_table
    group by
      user_id
   ) v
```

This way, the columns of the inner query can be decided as one, and the columns of the outer query can be decided as one. It might ever be faster, depending on the circumnstances.

Comment: @AdamKiss Generally, SQL happens in this order: FROM -> WHERE -> GROUP BY -> HAVING -> SELECT. That's why you can't use columns you define in the SELECT step in e.g. the GROUP BY or the WHERE. And since `SELECT a, b`  is supposed to be commutative to `SELECT b, a`, `a` and `b` can't know of each other.